# Build Xcode project using xcodebuild command

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, xcodebuild

I'm trying to automate a build for OSX's Xcode 7 project using `xcodebuild` command. The project is a static library, is written in C++ and should have a single target.

1. My project requires some files (let's say with extension **.B**) to be build before anything else happens (due to `#include`'s) using custom *build rule*. So I've added a build rule for *source files with names matching* and moved my **B** files **on top** of compile sources, which (as I've read) should ensure that they'll get compiled before other (.cpp) source files.
2. There are few other projects, that my project depends on, so those are sitting in *target dependancies*.

Everything works correctly, when the build is executed from Xcode itself, but when I'm trying to execute a build using `xcodebuild` command, no rules are applied, no ordering is ensured, target dependancies are not resolved and for some reason, compiler tries to link those **.B** files into resulting library.

Code I'm running is as easy as `xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -configuration Release`

The working solution to this, was having a separate target, which was built before the main target. The separate target only ran those build rules for **B**.

Question is: how to make `xcodebuild` behave the same way Xcode 7's *Build* command does - concerning build steps, compile order etc.